# liquid insulator by example?

Tags: power, transformer

can someone give me some example about liquid insulator .from some text which has been read by me it is just oil can someone told me the other one . it would be good if there is any book reference included some theory behind that

Comment: It is extremely difficult to understand what you are looking for.  Can you explain better?

Comment: i mean i am looking for some book reference about liquid insulator and the theory behind that

Answer (score 2):

You can read about liquid dielectrics (insulators) [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_dielectric).

I've seen a convincing demonstration of a CRT-based television set operating whilst completely immersed in clear liquid chlorofluorocarbon (back before they were severely limited by the [Montreal protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montreal_Protocol)).